# Access key scoping in WPF?

Tags: wpf, input, scoping

I have my XAML as follows,

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressed="OnKeyPressed">
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Background="Red"  x:Name="stack1">
        <ContentPresenter Content="_File" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="_Edit" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        <StackPanel Background="Green" Margin="5" x:Name="stack2">
            <ContentPresenter Content="_Food" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="_Earn" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The AccessKeyPressed event triggered for all these items and I want to restrict to a specific scope. For example, if I press Alt+F, only "File" item should be triggered and not "Food". How could I restrict this. I tried e.Handled = true;. And it does not help.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: And when should Alt+F trigger Food ?

Comment: Why don`t you want to use F_ood?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu : But that based on my internal logic. I will enable/disable the scope based on some previous user inputs.